# Django, which function belongs to QuerySet and Manager?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

I used to think QuerySet method return QuerySet instances, but it apparently not.

For instance, count() is a queryset method not manager's

How do I decide which functions go to custom QuerySet and which go to custom Manager class?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to be able to access some functions like `count()` on the manager *and* the queryset. This allows you to do:

```
Blog.objects.count()  # total number of blogs
Blog.objects.filter(status='PUBLISHED').count()  # Number of published blogs
```

Django has a method [`as_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods) which allows you to create a manager from a custom queryset. This means you don't have to duplicate your methods on the manager and queryset.