# django model manager or django queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I was reading django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/) and these two classes seemed similar,

here is the sample from django docs:

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def authors(self):
        return self.filter(role='A')

    def editors(self):
        return self.filter(role='E')

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PersonQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def authors(self):
        return self.get_queryset().authors()

    def editors(self):
        return self.get_queryset().editors()

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('A', _('Author')), ('E', _('Editor'))))
    people = PersonManager()
```

In the sample code as you can see code in `PersonQuerySet` can be moved to `PersonManager` (or move manager to query set) - my point is I can merge one to another without any problem)

so what is the difference between manager and queryset? do they have different use cases? or should I simply use one of them and ignore existance of the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a quirk. Basically if you want to write custom methods in your QuerySet **AND** you want to be able to access them through Manager class you **HAVE TO** also implement them in the Manager class. Which doesn't look great as it's not very DRY for Django that tries to be as DRY as possible, hence the helper as_manager().

So, to answer your question these are not two different cases, but rather an example for a special case where you want to use your custom QuerySet methods through a custom Manager.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the [from_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset) method on you manager to change its base Queryset.

This allows you to define your Queryset methods and your manager methods only once

from the docs

> For advanced usage you might want both a custom Manager and a custom QuerySet. You can do that by calling Manager.from_queryset() which returns a subclass of your base Manager with a copy of the custom QuerySet methods:

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def authors(self):
        return self.filter(role='A')

    def editors(self):
        return self.filter(role='E')

class BasePersonManager(models.Manager):
    pass

PersonManager = BasePersonManager.from_queryset(PersonQuerySet)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('A', _('Author')), ('E', _('Editor'))))
    people = PersonManager()
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is what is difference between manager and queryset? and knowing about the use cases.

Comment: managers are for table wide operation while the querysets are for a subset of records

Comment: @maazza The comment is very helpful, in one sentence everything became clear for me

Answer (score 0):

In order to stay DRY, django has this method [`as_manager()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.as_manager) where you do not have to duplicate the code needed in both.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240056/2996101) provides a very good example which answers the question about the difference of those two classes. I have added the `##` comments.

```
Blog.objects.count()  # Total number of blogs  ## Manager
Blog.objects.filter(status='PUBLISHED').count()  # Number of published blogs ## QuerySet
```

This is also clear in the following:

```
In [7]: type(MyModel.objects.filter())
Out[7]: django.db.models.query.QuerySet

In [8]: type(MyModel.objects)
Out[8]: django.db.models.manager.Manager
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is what is difference between manager and queryset? and knowing about the use cases.

Comment: @aliva I read the accepted answer and I did not understand what happens. When I read the linked answer, through this example which illustrates the difference (See the `##` at the end) I got the feeling, just a notion. For more details you should probably follow the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d5b0625cdf1abecca9511dd1edec4c1b610116ef/django/db/models/manager.py#L165).